# getting segmentation fault when a function included nested loop and ifs returns unexpected value

Tags: loops, class, oop, return, return-value

I'm trying to write a simple twitter-like program and when I want to new an object of my classes I get segmentation fault error here is part of my classes:

```
//Tweet.hpp file
class Tweet {

private:
   int tweetId;
   string text;
   string tweeterUser;
   int numOfLikes;
   int numOfRetweets;
   vector<string> tags;
   vector<Tweet*> commentsOrReplies;
   vector<string> mentions;
public:
   Tweet(int _jeekId, string _text, string _user) : jeekId(_tweetId), 
   text(_text), tweeterUser(_user),
   numOfRejeeks(0), numOfLikes(0) {}
   Tweet(int _tweetId, string _user) : tweetId(_jeekId), text(" "), 
   tweeterUser(_user) {}
   ~Tweet() {}
};
```

and this is where I want to new an instance of it:

```
//Tweeter.hpp file
class Tweeter {
private:
   vector<Tweet*> allTweets;
   vector<User*> allUsers;
   User* currentUser;
   Tweet* currenttweet;
public:
   vector<User*> getUsers() { return allUsers;}
   Tweeter() {}
   ~Tweeter() {}
   void tweet(string tweetText, int uniqueId);
};

  //Tweeter.cpp file
  void Tweeter::tweet(string tweetText, int uniqueId) {
      int currentUserPos = findTweetPosByTweetId(allUsers, 
      currentTweet->getTweetId());
      // Problem is in this line :
      Tweet* j = new Tweet(uniqueId, tweetText, 
            allUsers[currentUserPos]->getUsername());
        currentTweet = j;
 }
```

I'm probably sure that the problem comes from the return value of findTweetPosByTweetId() function whenever it can't find wantedTweet. which it's body is:

```
 int findTweetPosByTweetId(vector<Tweet*> allTweets, int 
     requestedTweetId) {
     int pos;
     for(int j = 0 ; j < allTweets.size() ; j++)
        if(allTweets[j]->getTweetId() == requestedTweetId)
            pos = j; 

return pos; 
}
```

but how can I edit it to return -1 whenever it couldn't find the Tweet, I've tried this but it was unsuccessful:

```
 int findTweetPosByTweetId(vector<Tweet*> allTweets, int 
     requestedTweetId) {
     int pos;
     for(int j = 0 ; j < allTweets.size() ; j++){
        if(allTweets[j]->getTweetId() == requestedTweetId)
            pos = j;
        else pos = -1;
     }

return pos; 
}
```

Comment: I suggest you debug your code line by line and figure out which line is problematic. What if currentTweet is null, or allUsers is empty or its size is less than the index you are trying to reach with your variable currentUserPos ?

Comment: @AlexG I actually did it and now I edited the text and I wrote where the problem is. I couldn't solve it because I think may be there are some rules which I haven't followed about allocating memory .

Comment: What does `findTweetPosByTweetId` return?  What is the meaning of the number it returns?  What does it return if it isn't found?

Comment: it returns an integer which is the position of a tweet in vector of a user's tweet. and it throw and can it throw an exception if it couldn't find?

Comment: If you want to keep the pointers in a vector, just use `std::shared_ptr`. This is the most simple solution.

Comment: Your syntax for 'new' seems fine but again, you might want to assert that currentUserPos < allUsers.size(). I'm pretty sure that's your problem.

Comment: As @AlexG pointed out, the problem has to be accessing beyond allUsers' size. What do you return when you cannot find a tweet?

Comment: The `new Tweet` line doesn't match `Tweet` constructor or am I missing something? Now that I look at this: what is `Jeek`? It looks like constructor but the class name is different. Does it even compile?

Comment: @AlexG  thank you. I'm going to check if the problem is with that function but Im not sure if t is

Comment: @kishore maybe I will set it to -1 if it couldn't find. I'm going to check if the problem is in this part. thank you

Comment: @shirazy by moving `allUsers[currentUserPos]->getUsername()` before `new Tweet` line you can easily verify that this line is problematic. By further decomposition you can check whether it is the problem with the index or `getUsername()`. All of that should be easy verifiable with proper debuging tool.

Comment: @freakish I edited the question. but it wasn't the proble. Jeek is Tweet in my language :)) I changed it to publish here and I forgot some parts

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: please reopen this question I have edited and added the specific area where the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

compile with debug option on (-g for g++) , run in gdb and you will immediately have the offending line of code. If you're new to gdb (assuming you're on Linux) , use the -tui interface... makes life so much easier when navigating.

Hope that helps.

G

Comment: Or, use an IDE, with a built in debugger, plus other features. The debugger is your #1 best friend